# Confused about re.compile behaviour

Tags: python, regex

Please help me understand why the code in CODE2 is working. My understanding is that `re.compile` returns an object and we specify methods like `search`, `match`, `findall` etc to obtain the desired result.

What I am confused about is how `re` module level functions like search is able to accept the compiled abject as the parameter. Please see CODE2

CODE1:

```
In [430]: p = re.compile(r'(\b\w+)\s+\1')
In [431]: p.search('Paris in the the spring').group()
Out[431]:
'the the'
```

CODE 2

```
In [432]: re.search(p, 'Paris in the the spring').group()
Out[432]:
'the the'
```

Answer (score 3):

`re.search`'s first argument is documented as being a **re pattern string**, i.e, **not** a compiled RE object -- maybe a better design would have been to accept either polymorphically, but, alas!, back when the `re` module was being developed, that's just not how we did it.  Ah well, at least it's just the same across all module functions in `re` that mimic the methods of `re` compiled objects!-)

**However**, at some point in Python's long and storied history, somebody fixed our original mis-design (I can't say when that happened!): nowadays, while for most `re` function the first `pattern` argument is still said to have to be a RE pattern string, a few are now documented as "may be a string or an RE object"... and **all** of them appear to work that (better!) way.

So if you have a compiled `re`, **in theory**, according to (most of) the docs, you need to call its methods (and it's generally the best approach, except in the very shortest of snippets) rather than pass it to `re` module level functions such as `re.search`.  But **in practice**, a compiled `re` object will be just as fine as an as-documented RE pattern.

Man, good thing I got aware of this just as I start preparing (with two co-authors) the third edition of "Python in a Nutshell"... at least I'll get to "fix the docs" for **that**!-)

Added: to measure speed, as usual, `timeit` is your friend!

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import re; s="paris in the spring"; mre=re.compile("paris")' 're.match("paris", s)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 usec per loop
```

versus:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import re; s="paris in the spring"; mre=re.compile("paris")' 'mre.match(s)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.468 usec per loop
```

So, overall, you can get about 3 times faster by `re.compile`ing things once, than by letting a `re` function handle everything for you.  See why I'm a fan of the `re.compile` approach?-)

Moreover, in Python, "faster" tends to correlate strongly with "more Pythonic" ("idiomatic in Python", in other words).  When you're unsure which of two approached is more Pythonic, `timeit` them properly (preferably using the command-line approach `python -mtimeit`), and if either approach is reliably faster, you have your answer: that approach is more Pythonic!-)

Comment: What does 'alas' mean?

Comment: Per a web search on `define:alas`, it is "an expression of grief, pity, or concern".  I was actually using it as an expression of **regret** (for my responsibility in possibly helping mis-design that module, or rather letting the possible mis-design sail through -- far too late to change it now!-) but I'd hope that's close enough to "grief, pity, or concern" (as English is my third language, I can never be fully confident if I'm using it correctly, though my American-born-and-bred wife and my editors all maintain I use it better than most native speakers...:-).

Comment: Well English is my not main that's why I asked :-)

Comment: Oh!  Somebody **did** fix the original mis-design -- I see that now some of the `re` functions are documented with the first argument `pattern` "may be a string or an RE object" (not all!) but all appear to work this way.  Better edit my answer, though I don't know WHEN the fix happened...

Comment: I think I read somewhere that CPython's implementation may intern regular expressions using compiled regular expression objects.  In those cases (where the interning is effective) there should be no difference between calling re.function(some_re, ...) and some_re.method(...); I wonder if this apparent polymorphism emerged from that?

Comment: @JimDennis: Interesting! So if I use CPython I'm just wasting time compiling regexes... I don't know if that's a good thing or a bad thing. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring, no time wasted -- if you compile your regexes you're, at worst, just doing the work `re` functions would do for you (and that, only for a bounded number of regexes -- that cache is not unbounded!-).  Except in the simplest snippets, taking control of your fate and compiling the regular expressions you're using repeatedly (then calling their methods, not `re` functions) is stil the best practice.

Comment: @AlexMartelli: I thought that it might be slightly more efficient to let the `re` functions do the work for me. But good point about the cache not being unbounded. And I just think it looks neater to explicitly compile the patterns.

Comment: @PM2Ring, the `re` functions are one level of indirection, thus, can't be quite as fast.  As usual, `timeit` helps you calibrate; editing my A to show that.

Comment: Yes.  My comment was not meant to suggest that explicitly compiling regular expressions is a "waste of time."  I was merely trying to add to the understanding of underlying mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

All of the functions in the `re` module allow you to specify a pattern object instead of a pattern string.  It is simply an optimization/convenience feature that allows you to avoid building a new pattern object if you already have one.

---

I was unable find a docs link which explicitly mentions this behavior, but you can see it quite easily if you view the source code<sup>1</sup>.  To start, the [implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/37c6fd09f71f/Lib/re.py#l222) for `re.compile` is:

```
def compile(pattern, flags=0):
    "Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a pattern object."
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
```

Notice how this function does nothing but call another function named `_compile`.  This function is what actually builds a pattern object.  `re.compile` is just an alias for it.

---

Moving on, the [implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/37c6fd09f71f/Lib/re.py#l170) for `re.search` is:

```
def search(pattern, string, flags=0):
    """Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning
    a match object, or None if no match was found."""
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
```

As you can see, there is also nothing special about the `re.search` function.  It just calls the `search` method of the pattern object returned by `re._compile`.  This means that doing:

```
re.search(p, 'Paris in the the spring').group()
```

is the same as:

```
re._compile(p).search('Paris in the the spring').group()
```

---

So the question you should be asking is why `re._compile` allows you to pass a pattern object as a pattern string.  As before, the answer can be found by looking at the [implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/37c6fd09f71f/Lib/re.py#l278):

```
def _compile(pattern, flags):
    ...
    if isinstance(pattern, _pattern_type):
        if flags:
            raise ValueError(
                "Cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern")
        return pattern
```

As you can see, the `_compile` function does a check to see if its `pattern` argument is already a pattern object.  If so, it simply returns it and avoids building a new one.  This means that doing:

```
re.search(p, 'Paris in the the spring').group()
```

is equivalent to:

```
re._compile(p).search('Paris in the the spring').group()
```

which becomes:

```
p.search('Paris in the the spring').group()
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>This is the source code for CPython.</sub>